# How to make text rendering as sharp as internet explorer in chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, text

Unlike the usual complaints people have about ie, I have been noticing my site looks excellent in IE but pretty 'meh' in other browsers. The text looks far sharper in ie, whereas it looks jagged in chrome, safari etc.

On a not so positive note, most of the time the transitions do not complete in ie, any idea how to fix?

It literally stops about halfway there.

```
     -webkit-transition-property:color, background; 
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.5s; 
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-property:color, background; 
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.5s; 
 -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-property:color, background; 
 -o-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.5s; 
 -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition-property:color, background; 
 -ms-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.5s; 
 -ms-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
```

Thats not too much of an issue but if anyone has a fix for that it would be good.

Anyway, how can I make the text look as good in Chrome/Safari/Firefox as it does in ie?

[image: IE vs other browsers]

This demonstrates how big a difference there is

Answer (score 0):

Try do add in your CSS

```
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Made it a little better, still a little too blurry though

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
```

Also, if you use @font-face, you can force Chrome to render the svg format instead of the woff, which is usually rendering badly in Chrome (if it's the case)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
        src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* Add this block below the above block */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'MyWebFont';
            src: url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
}
```

You might also see some improvements if using Webkit's specific [-webkit-text-stroke](https://www.webkit.org/blog/85/introducing-text-stroke/):

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
```

Comment: I'm using some fonts from google's font API and they only support woff. Ironic.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you're happy with IE rendering, I think it's safe to assume you are having issues with Chrome for Windows. This has actually been an ongoing issue, but the consensus is [it's been finally addressed](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/chrome-35-beta-more-developer-control.html) in Chrome 35 beta. Sometimes a bug is just a bug!

[image: Chrome 34 vs Chrome 35 beta]

Image courtesy of [/r/web_design/](http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/22q9r9/chrome_35_beta_has_finally_fixed_windows_font/)